# How to retrieve the real definition of a type, variable, macro etc. from the C language headers?

Tags: c, gcc

Nowadays, C language compiler environments are quite complicated. I often encounter problems on determining the actual definition of a type, variable, function, or macro as defined in some header file as it is activated by the current compiler options.

The included files have conditional definitions, conditional inclusions, etc. depending on the compiler options selecting which language "standard" to use during a specific compilation. So, it is quite difficult to retrieve the actual definition of structure (for example) conditionally defined deep in some header. I need a method to display or pinpoint its actual definition.

For example, take the definition of `struct tm` which is supposed to be defined in `time.h`. However, you are not going to find it there in the *GNU Project C Compiler*.

I can always, refer to documents (ISO/IEC 9899 Standard or GCC Online Documentation), but there may be some cases where the definition will change depending on which Standard or non-standard compiler environment I select. So, the question is:

**How can I list the real definition of a function prototype, macro, variable, or type as it is being processed by the current activation of the compiler subject to the selected compile-time options?**

---

Some examples:

- Find the value of macro `EOF` in `stdio.h`.
- Find the definition of "type" `FILE` in `stdio.h`.
- Find the definition of `assert` macro in `assert.h`.
- Find the definition of `struct timespec` in `time.h`.
- What is the meaning of `__restrict` in the prototype definition of `fopen` in `stdio.h`?

Comment: Most compilers will have an option to produce preprocessed output. For `gcc` the option is `-E`.

Comment: One option would be to `#include` the resp. in a C source (which might even be empty) and compile it with `-E` (pre-processor-only run) and your other compiler options.

Comment: the compiler is not responsible of the definition of *tm* which is not part of the language => look at the included files, may be helped by options like `-E` for gcc

Comment: MS VC has an option (button) to go to the (active) definition/declaration of a symbol. Maybe other IDEs have this possibility too.

Comment: Standard headers often `#include` implementation-specific headers that contain the actual definitions - it’s mainly a matter of chasing down those additional files.  Like `errno.h`often includes a `sys/errno.h` that contains the actual error codes.  `stdio.h` typically includes multiple implementation-specific headers.

Comment: That is right @JohnBode I just don't want to do this chasing! :)

Answer (score 2):

> How can I list the real definition of a function prototype, macro, variable, or type as it is being processed by the current activation of the compiler subject to the selected compile-time options?

From within the C language itself, you can't. C language doesn't have [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflective_programming), it can't inspect itself.

Going to a type definition, navigating and browsing through a source code tree - these are jobs for an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) that is integrated with C programming language, this is not part of a programming language itself. There are vast number of [IDEs available that integrate with C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C/C++), there are [language servers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Server_Protocol), and there are C code indexers like [ctags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ctags), [GNU global](https://www.gnu.org/software/global/manual/global.html). Configure the indexing tool or IDE with the same options and macros you provide your compiler with and the tool will help you through code. There are also [build systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_build_automation_software) integrated with IDE, so that the compiler invoked by the build system uses same command line arguments as the indexer automatically (like with the help of [compile_commands.json](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/JSONCompilationDatabase.html) in case of `cmake`).

> For example, take the definition of struct tm

For example, install eclipse with the C and C++ plugins installed. Create new `C/C++ project`, create there `some.c` file and type in it `#include <time.h>` followed by `struct tm;`. Save the file, let the eclipse indexer index the project (should be instantaneous) or click on `Project->C/C++ Index->Rebuild`. Then put the cursor on `tm` string and click `F3` -> viola, on my pc cursor goes into `/usr/include/bits/types/struct_tm.h` file.

> But, my question was related to command line compilers like gcc
> How to retrieve the real definition of a type, variable, macro etc. from the C language headers?

`gcc` is a compiler - it does not support such feature.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, my question was related to command line compilers like `gcc`.

Comment: I do not understand. Compiler translate code from one language to another. Compilers do not "list the real definition of a function prototype". They compile - that's the primarily job. The job of a language server that may be integrated with a compiler (like clang) may be  "listing the definition of a function protype".

Comment: I do no use IDEs. I would like to see some methods to get the required output from _command line_. For example, after doing some more research, I found that some simple preprocessor file definitions may easily obtained like this `echo '' | cpp --include stddef.h | grep ptrdiff`. However, I need a method to see similar definitions from the compiler point of view.

Comment: The use a command line indexer, index the code, use the generated database to find the result. Typically `ctags`+`cscope`.